# To display only custom categorie image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Newbie to writing PHP.
I have created  CPT (gallery) with eight posts.
I have also created custom taxonomy (categorie) with eight categories.
Using Advanced Custom Field I have uploaded one image in categorie.
There are two posts which have same categorie.

"I want to display only category image and name in one page."

After clicking that category name or image it should move to another page displaying related posts to that category.
Bt I am getting an issue in displaying category image and name.
For my code it is displaying two times the category image and name, because two posts having same categorie.

[Front End]

```
<?php /* Template Name: hometemp*/ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'categorie',
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'fields'     => 'all'
) );
?>
<?php
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'gallery',
    'categorie' => $term->slug   
);
$term_link = get_term_link( $term );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <a class="property-thumb-link"
               href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
                <div class="property-thumb column medium-6 small-12">
                <div class="property-thumb-title">
                        <h2>
                        <div class="property-thumb-title">
                        <h2>

                        <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                        </h2>

                    </div>
                        </h2>

                    </div>

                    <div>
                <div >
                <?php $image = get_field('category_image', $term);?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" alt="" srcset="" height=400 width=300>
            </div>

     </div>
     </div>

            </a>
         <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
     endif; }?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try below code:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'category',
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'fields'     => 'all'
) );
?>
<?php
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
$term_link = get_term_link( $term );
?>
    <a class="property-thumb-link"
       href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
        <div class="property-thumb column medium-6 small-12">
        <div class="property-thumb-title">
            <h2>
                <div class="property-thumb-title">
                    <h2>
                    <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <?php $image = get_field('test_one', $term);?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image;?>" alt="" srcset="" height=400 width=300>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php }?>
```